# How to configure DriverManagerDataSource using PropertiesFactoryBean in spring

Tags: spring, configuration, datasource

I am having hard time configuring datasource for my application. DriverManagerDataSource is not able to read properties from properties files.

Here is relevant section of applicationContext.xml :-

```
<bean id="selfPublishProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:selfpublish-dev.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:jdbc-dev.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
     <bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>
```

The error message just says could not load driver ${jdbc.driverClassName} . The jdbc-dev.properties has this entry like this :-

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

It has other entries also like username, password etc but spring fails at driverClassname itself.

If I put this line in applicationContext.xml , then it is all fine :-

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="selfPublishProperties" />
```

But that is not what I want to do. I want to configure my datasource using PropertiesFactoryBean only and not using PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you want to use PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer?

Comment: I looked up differences between the two and found this :- 
PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer is a BeanFactoryPostProcessor implementation that reads a property file and uses that property file to replace placeholder variables (${somename}) with actual values. The read properties aren't available as a Properties object.  I need properties to be available as java.util.properties object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is how it supposed to work. PropertySourcePlaceHolderConfigurer is supposed to resolve ${...} placeholders while PropertiesFactoryBean exposes a java.util.Properties instance.

Here are relevant documentation links :-

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html